# SQL Server Agent Job Completion E-mail Notification

Tags: sql-server, email, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I've created a Database Mail account (tested and sends with no problem), created an operator, set up an alert on the job I want to monitor, and restarted my SQL Server Agent.  But I still am not alerted when the job in question completes.  Is there a step that is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get notifications to start sending after a server restart

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Database Mail log and make sure you don't have any errors sending there. Make sure your internal relay mail servers allow sending from the SQL server's IP address. Also run `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp` and make sure the dbmail queue status is "Started" or "Receives_Occuring". If the queue is in a Stopped status, restart it with `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_stop_sp` and `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp`

Comment: I can send test e-mails using the Database mail log.  This is an issue with something else

Answer (score 0):

Open the job, go to notifications and select Email, choose the operator you created, and the condition "When the job fails". That should do it.